# Send push notifications to a newly registered device

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I want to send previous notifications to newly registered devices.

How can I do this, and with which free services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save that notification for future use and when any new user registers then you need to send that notification to that users. The notification service is provided by google's **firebase notification**. You can use the **firebase notification** services which is freely available for all google users.
You can refer to this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/

Comment: ok but can do it automaticly ? (save then send ?)

Comment: Yes, it is automatic when user register you need to check that any previous notifications is available if available then you need to call send notification to all that records in while loop.